# Белый цвет вокруг букв.

Tags: html

В результате должны быть слово из чёрных буквы, каждая буква обведена белым цветом. Можно ли это сделать с помощью html? С помощью каких тегов?

Comment: @Наташенька, а почему только html, какова причина нежелания добавить правила CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Наташенька](/users/5963/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0)](/users/5963/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0), попробуйте так:

```
 <body style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000;">
    <p style="color: #000; text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff; text-align: center; margin-top: 100px; font: bold 50px Comic;">Наташенька, удачи!</p>
 </body>
```

Вот **[рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/JrVfL/3/)**.

P.s. Я бы Вам не рекомендовал прописывать стили внутри тегов, лучше вынести в отдельный CSS - файл, ну или на крайний случай, хотя бы в head.

Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо) проблема решена без помощи хтмль) внутренними возможностями Android)

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример, сделанный при помощи CSS, но работает не во всех браузерах

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
#element {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<span id="element">Example</span>
</body>
</html>
```

подробнее про text-shadow и где он работает, можно прочитать [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-shadow)

Comment: а без css вообще никак нельзя. мне надо, чтобы только html был)

Comment: @Наташенька, только html нет.

Comment: @Sever, на будущее, 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

Comment: Я пример привел, не особо вдавался в meta, я это к тому, что будущее в порядке.

Comment: @Crasher, какое отношение meta и DTD имеют к CSS?

Comment: @Наташенька, как уже отметил stck, к сожалению, нет

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/6550/klopp

Comment: Так там был указан DTD :) Или в HTML 4.01 Transitional некорректно понимается CSS 2/3?

Comment: Да. Этот доктайп переключает в режим quirks mode тоже.